# Python: min(None, x)

Tags: python, python-2.x

I would like to perform the following:

```
a=max(a,3)
b=min(b,3)
```

However sometimes `a` and `b` may be `None`.
I was happy to discover that in the case of `max` it works out nicely, giving my required result `3`, however if `b` is `None`, `b` remains `None`...

Anyone can think of an elegant little trick to make `min` return the number in case one of the arguments in None?

Comment: It doesn't do the right thing. It happens to give the result you expect in one of two cases because the nonsensical comparision between `NoneType` and `int` returns a fixed value regardless of the integer value. In Python 3, you get a `TypeError` when you do things like that (comparing types that have no meaningful ordering).

Comment: Seems like an inconsistency in Python, more than anything else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214194/is-everything-greater-than-none

Comment: if you are ok with replacing None to a default int value (like 0), you can do something like this: `max(a,3,key=lambda x: x or 0)`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Why don't you just create a generator without None values? It's simplier and cleaner.

```
>>> l=[None ,3]
>>> min(i for i in l if i is not None)
3
```

Comment: No need for the list comprehension. Still +1 (in advance - seriously, please remove the brackets), it's a clean and simple solution.

Comment: Thanks, without the braces, does Python interprets it like a generator expression?

Comment: Yes. The parens around generator expressions are optional if the genexpr is the sole argument to a function call.

Comment: One potential problem with a solution like this is that it works fine for the listed example but if you have a list with `[None, None]`, the `min()` function will fail because you're not giving it a valid argument.

Comment: @KevinLondon, specify the default value for the min as 0 or None depending upon the behavior you want. ```min((x for x in [None,None] if x is not None), default=None)```

Answer (score 10):

My solution for Python 3 (3.4 and greater):

```
min((x for x in lst if x is not None), default=None)
max((x for x in lst if x is not None), default=None)
```

Answer (score 7):

A solution for the Python 3

**Code**:

*# variable lst is your sequence*

```
min(filter(lambda x: x is not None, lst)) if any(lst) else None
```

**Examples:**

```
In [3]: lst = [None, 1, None]

In [4]: min(filter(lambda x: x is not None, lst)) if any(lst) else None
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: lst = [-4, None, 11]

In [6]: min(filter(lambda x: x is not None, lst)) if any(lst) else None
Out[6]: -4

In [7]: lst = [0, 7, -79]

In [8]: min(filter(lambda x: x is not None, lst)) if any(lst) else None
Out[8]: -79

In [9]: lst = [None, None, None]

In [10]: min(filter(lambda x: x is not None, lst)) if any(lst) else None

In [11]: print(min(filter(lambda x: x is not None, lst)) if any(lst) else None)
None
```

**Notes:**

Worked in sequence presents as numbers as well as None. If all values is None min() raise exception

> ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

This code resolve this problem at all

**Pros:**

1. Worked if None presents in sequence
2. Worked on Python 3
3. max() will be work also

**Cons**

1. Need more than one non-zero variable in the list. i.e. [0,None] fails.
2. Need a variable (example *lst*) or need duplicate the sequence

Comment: This also works for Python 2.7. Since it also resolves the min(None) problem of the other solutions, it gets my +1

Comment: A boundary case that this does not handle is if it is possible for `lst` to contain only 0 and None values. You would want it to return 0, but it will return None.

Comment: Great answer and examples!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a decorator that you can use to filter out None values that might be passed to a function:

```
def no_nones(fn):
    def _inner(*args):
        return fn(a for a in args if a is not None)
    return _inner

print no_nones(min)(None, 3)
print no_nones(max)(None, 3)
```

prints:

```
3
3
```

Comment: Cleaned up to use def instead of lambda, also changed to a PEP8-compliant name.

Answer (score 3):

```
def max_none(a, b):
    if a is None:
        a = float('-inf')
    if b is None:
        b = float('-inf')
    return max(a, b)

def min_none(a, b):
    if a is None:
        a = float('inf')
    if b is None:
        b = float('inf')
    return min(a, b)

max_none(None, 3)
max_none(3, None)
min_none(None, 3)
min_none(3, None)
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the default is 0. Passing 0 instead of `None` still triggers passing the default but doesn't change the value since the default is 0 (and `0 == 0.0 == 0j`).

Comment: The OP said max was not a problem. Also what happens if b is negative ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an inline `if` and an infinity as the default, as that will work for any value:

```
a = max(a if a is not None else float('-inf'), 3)
b = min(b if b is not None else float('inf'), 3)
```

Comment: Okay, then I'll make it a bit more explicit

Comment: Then this will pass `True` on occasion ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
a=max(a,3) if a is not None else 3
b=min(b,3) if b is not None else 3
```

Comment: I always try to avoid negations. So I prefer `b = 3 if b is None else min(b, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

@utdemir's answer works great for the provided example but would raise an error in some scenarios.

One issue that comes up is if you have a list with only `None` values. If you provide an empty sequence to `min()`, it will raise an error:

```
>>> mylist = [None, None]
>>> min(value for value in mylist if value)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

As such, this snippet would prevent the error:

```
def find_minimum(minimums):
    potential_mins = (value for value in minimums if value is not None)
    if potential_mins:
        return min(potential_mins)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cleanest way is to use filter built-in function

```
a = max(filter(None, [a, 3]))
b = min(filter(None, [b, 3]))
```

Comment: This filters out zeros.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use np.nan instead of None:

```
import numpy as np
float(np.nanmax([a, np.nan]))
float(np.nanmin([a, np.nan]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @PADYMKO's answer you can also use numpy array `.any()` to filter zeros from `None` if your array contains both :

```py
>>> lst = np.asarray(lst)
>>> min(filter(lambda x: x is not None, lst)) if (lst != None).any() else None
```

Results :

```py
>>> lst = [None, None]
>>> lst= np.array(lst)
>>> min(filter(lambda x: x is not None, lst)) if (lst != None).any() else None

>>> lst = [0, None]
>>> lst= np.array(lst)
>>> min(filter(lambda x: x is not None, lst)) if (lst != None).any() else None
0

>>> lst = [0, -5, 2, None]
>>> lst= np.array(lst)
>>> min(filter(lambda x: x is not None, lst)) if (lst != None).any() else None
-5
```