# Comparing None with built-in types using arithmetic operators?

Tags: python, comparison, cpython

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> None > 0
False
>>> None == 0
False
>>> None < 0
True
```

- Is comparing `None` using arithmetic operators well defined for built-in types (integers in this case)?
- Is the difference between the first two and the third comparison part of language specification (Python's specification - you must be kidding :)) or is it CPython's implementation detail?

Comment: `==` and `!=` are usually safe, but you are supposed to use `is None` and `is not None` for singletons such as `None` as per [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: @ThiefMaster The whole point of the question is what does *safe* mean here. I'm well aware one should use `is` to compare with `None` but question is specific and does not ask about which operator should be used.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue1673405

Comment: Duplicate: [Is everything greater than None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214194/is-everything-greater-than-none)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The only meaningful comparison you can really use with `None` is `if obj is None:` (or `if obj is not None:`).

Comparison between different types has been removed from Python 3 for good reasons - they were a common source of errors and lead to confusion. For example

```
>>> "3" < 4
False
```

In Python 3, you get a `TypeError` when comparing values of different types like `str` vs. `int` or anything vs. `None`.

```
>>> None < 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()
```

(I mean "comparing" in the sense of trying to determine which of two values is larger/smaller. Comparison for equality is OK - it will always return `False` if two object are of different types.)

I haven't found a reference in the docs for this, but in [Learning Python, 4th edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596158071.do), Mark Lutz writes on page 204:

> [...] Comparisons of differently typed objects (e.g., a string and a
>   list) work — the language defines a fixed ordering among different
>   types, which is deterministic, if not aesthetically pleasing. That is,
>   the ordering is based on the names of the types involved: all integers
>   are less than all strings, for example, because `"int"` is less than
>   `"str"`.

Comment: What is the technical reason why `None < 0` is true?

Comment: @wim: `None` is the "lowest type" in Python 2, so `None` is always lower than any `int` which is always lower than any `str` etc.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: Don't know, but I've added a quote from Mark Lutz's book "Learning Python" (highly recommended).

Comment: *(...) the language defines a fixed ordering among different types (...) That is, the ordering is based on the names of the types involved* is in contradiction with *(...) objects of different types will compare according to an ordering on their types (an implementation dependent, (...)* cited in wim's answer. Where's the truth?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used python, so I'm probably missing something really obvious. What do you mean by "comparison for identity"? I thought that we used "is" for that purpose. Please do let me know.

Comment: @batbrat: Sorry, I meant equality. Thanks for spotting this error. Fixed.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks for fixing it :)

Answer (score 6):

Some interesting quotes from http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/801701-why-none-0-a

> In early Python, the decision was made that the comparison of *any*
>   two objects was legal and would return a consistent result. So objects
>   of different types will compare according to an ordering on their
>   types (an implementation dependent, unspecified, but consistent
>   ordering), and objects of the same type will be compared according to
>   rules that make sense for that type.
>
> Other implementations have the right to compare an integer and None
>   differently, but on a specific implementation, the result will not
>   change.
>
> Python 3 will raise an exception on such comparisons.

and

> The problem is the typical one; Python did not originally have a
>   Boolean type, and the retrofit resulted in weird semantics. C has the
>   same issue.

Comment: This is really sick. Another reason to avoid Python 3 as long as possible. So you can't sort a list of heterogenous objects as of now... `>>> sorted([2, 1.5, 2.5])
[1.5, 2, 2.5]
>>> sorted([2, 1.5, 2.5, 'bla', '2', '2.5', None])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()`.

Comment: I would argue that as a reason to _prefer_ python 3.. What is the expected result from `sorted([2, 1.5, 2.5, 'bla', '2', '2.5', None])` ?

Comment: @TomaszGandor Reading your comment in 2021 

Comment: @moveaway00 - `[None, 1.5, 2, 2.5, '2', '2.5', 'bla']`, and without checking I would at least say that `None` should come first (and numbers before strings? this also makes some sense). @jtlz2 - yes, much has changed since then. One such thing was the good old Python 3.6.