# python sorting two lists - zip, sort, zip - unorderable types: int() < NoneType()

Tags: python, sorting

I have two lists:

```
a_list = ['a', 'k', 'a']
c_list = [[None, None], [13, None], ['f', None]]
```

I would like to sort a_list and c_list to be arranged according to order of a_list. So after sorting I would like to have:

```
a_list = ['a', 'a', 'k']
c_list = [[None, None], ['f', None], [13, None]]
```

I am trying to do it with `zip`, `sort`, `zip` approach, but it gives me error message at the following stage:

```
a_c_zip = sorted(zip(a_list,c_list))

TypeError: unorderable types: int() < NoneType()
```

I think this is happening because of ambiguity of two `a` values, but I wonder if there is a work-around? After all sorting a_list works without any problem

I don't really want to write my own sorting routine since it will be very slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to specify the key on which to sort. Provided that you don't care about the order in which the two "a" entries get sorted, you can just tell `sorted` to look at the first element of each pair generated by `zip` (where each pair contains one element from `a_list` followed by one element from `c_list`).

```
>>> a_list = ['a', 'k', 'a']
>>> c_list = [[None, None], [13, None], ['f', None]]
>>> sorted(zip(a_list, c_list), key=lambda pair: pair[0])
[('a', [None, None]), ('a', ['f', None]), ('k', [13, None])]
```

If you do care about how the two "a" entries get sorted (that is, you want them to be ordered in a way that depends on the corresponding entries in `c_list`), you'll need to figure out how you want `None`, integers, and strings to sort against each other.

One possibility is to treat `None` as `''` and numbers as their string representations, and take advantage of the fact that Python sorts iterables by the values of their elements from left to right:

```
>>> sorted(zip(a_list, c_list),
       key=lambda pair: (pair[0], ['' if elem is None else str(elem) for elem in pair[1]]))
[('a', [None, None]), ('a', ['f', None]), ('k', [13, None])]
```

Or something along those lines.

The reason you get the TypeError is that `sorted` tries to compare `('a', [None, None])` against `('a', ['f', None])`. Since the 0th element of both tuples are the same, it has to compare the 1st element. Since both have an iterable as the 1st element, it compares `[None, None]` against `['f', None]` elementwise. But to do so, it must compare `'f'` against `None`, and [you can't compare `None` against stuff in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8961036/) (though you could in Python 2).

Comment: python [sorted is stable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915376/is-pythons-sorted-function-guaranteed-to-be-stable), so the first 'a' in the unsorted list should always come first in the sorted list.

Comment: @senshin Thank you for such a comprehensive answer. I was thinking to try the following suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422700/how-to-get-indices-of-a-sorted-array-in-python