# How to declare a variable in Python without assigning a value to it like MATLAB?

Tags: python, integration

I want to calculate ***indefinite integration*** in ***Python***...So how can i get a variable without assigning value to it...

Comment: #Check-out the question in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47865586/9112578)

Comment: @MSD I used Sympy library and also posted that as an answer but someone downvoted my answer.

Comment: @MSD Thanks btw

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using Sympy library in Python.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `value = None`. More information can be found in [this related SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664294/is-it-possible-only-to-declare-a-variable-without-assigning-any-value-in-python)

It would helpful if we could see an example of exactly what you are trying to do so we could help your problem specifically.

Comment: I know you can't add comments yet but why post this answer when it has already been provided as a **comment** by Peter?

Comment: I hadn't seen the comment in the time that I posted this. I came to the post before his comment and posted after his comment. I mean, I could delete it if its really that important, but I feel that the related link is helpful in this case.

Comment: @DimitrisJim Comments are usually used for clarification and discussion that is not directly answering the question. A question on SO is considered answered only when an answer has been provided and accepted. That is a signal to people that THIS is the answer and the solution WORKS.

Answer (score 1):

Because python is not like C or java or so, when you declare a new variable you don't have to indicate the type explicitly. Thus you can't leave a blank after the variable name to make it valueless. 
For python a wise way to do so is to **actually assign** a '*noun*' value to it.

> *variable_name* = None

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a variable without assigning value to it like this:

```
variable = []
```

Comment: but can it be raised to **power** ???....like x=[] and can i do x**2 or x**3 with it?? .....actually i want to do **integration** ....

Comment: None is more suitable for it instead of an array.