# Python: replace french letters with english

Tags: python, string, ascii, french

I would like to replace all the french letters within words with their ASCII equivalent.

```
letters = [['é', 'à'], ['è', 'ù'], ['â', 'ê'], ['î', 'ô'], ['û', 'ç']]

for x in letters:
   for a in x:
        a = a.replace('é', 'e')
        a = a.replace('à', 'a')
        a = a.replace('è', 'e')
        a = a.replace('ù', 'u')
        a = a.replace('â', 'a')
        a = a.replace('ê', 'e')
        a = a.replace('î', 'i')
        a = a.replace('ô', 'o')
        a = a.replace('û', 'u')
        a = a.replace('ç', 'c')

print(letters[0][0])
```

This code prints `é` however. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

May I suggest you consider using [translation tables](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans).

```
translationTable = str.maketrans("éàèùâêîôûç", "eaeuaeiouc")

test = "Héllô Càèùverâêt Jîôûç"
test = test.translate(translationTable)
print(test)
```

will print `Hello Caeuveraet Jiouc`.  Pardon my French.

Comment: your french is bad, but your knowledge of python is good. and it's probably the fastest performance-wise.

Comment: Is that the complete list?

Answer (score 19):

You can also use `unidecode`. Install it: `pip install unidecode`.
Then, do:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

s = "Héllô Càèùverâêt Jîôûç ïîäüë"
s = unidecode(s)
print(s)  # Hello Caeuveraet Jiouc iiaue
```

The result will be the same string, but the french characters will be converted to their ASCII equivalent: `Hello Caeuveraet Jiouc iiaue`

Answer (score 3):

The `replace` function returns the string with the character replaced.

In your code you don't store this return value.

The lines in your loop should be `a = a.replace('é', 'e')`.

You also need to store that output so you can print it in the end.

---

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423118/python-list-for-each-access-find-replace-in-built-in-list) explains how variables within loops are accessed.

Comment: This won't work. `letters` will not be mutated by simply assigning the result of `replace` to `a`

Comment: That's why I added the last sentence, the "a" is a copy of the value in in x (which is a copy of the value in letters). Those loops are not passing a reference

Comment: No, they are not copies. That is *certainly not* how Python works.

Answer (score 2):

Although I am new to Python, I would approach it this way:

```
letterXchange = {'à':'a', 'â':'a', 'ä':'a', 'é':'e', 'è':'e', 'ê':'e', 'ë':'e',
    'î':'i', 'ï':'i', 'ô':'o', 'ö':'o', 'ù':'u', 'û':'u', 'ü':'u', 'ç':'c'}
text = input() # Replace it with the string in your code.
for item in list(text):
    if item in letterXchange:
        text = text.replace(item,letterXchange.get(str(item)))
    else:
        pass
print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, using the low level unicode package called `unicodedata`.

In the unicode structure, a character like 'ô' is actually a **composite character**, made of the character 'o' and another character called '**COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT**', which is basically the '̀'. Using the method `decomposition` in `unicodedata`, one can obtain the unicodes (in hex) of these two parts.

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.decomposition('ù')
'0075 0300'
>>> chr(0x0075)
'u'
>>> >>> chr(0x0300)
'̀'
```

Therefore, to retrieve 'u' from 'ù', we can first do a string split, then use the built-in `int` function for the conversion(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python) thread for converting a hex string to an integer), and then get the character using `chr` function.

```
import unicodedata as ud

def get_ascii_char(c):
    s = ud.decomposition(c)
    if s == '': # for an indecomposable character, it returns ''
        return c
    code = int('0x' + s.split()[0], 0)
    return chr(code)
```