# Why there is no error without using global keyword

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, global-variables, global

In [this file](https://github.com/knoxxs/InfoRescue/blob/characterModel/src/features/characterErrorModel.py) I am using a dictionary named `modelDict` declared globally and I am using it in multiple functions (`addCharToModelDict, dumpModelDict`). I haven't used `global` keyword inside these functions to use the global `modelDict`.
`addCharToModelDict` is updating it and `dumpModelDict` is writing it back to file in the end.

Everything works fine!!

**Why this is happening?? Isn't using global keyword is necessary??**

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Python, why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/in-python-why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `global` keyword is only required when **rebinding** the name. Your operations **mutate** the object instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are working with `modelDict` variable from `globals` (python trying to find `modelDict` in locals but can't then It tries to find it in `globals` and succeeded). This works If You use variable defined in outer code either read or update.

```
d = {}
def foo():
    a = d.get('x')
    d[4] = True
foo()
```

If You will try to reassign new data to variable with this name (rebind it) You will get Error.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> def foo():
        a = d.get('x')
        d = {4: True}

>>> foo()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'd' referenced before assignment
```