# Why int object in Python is seen localy scope by default?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, scope

See the code below:

```
i = 1
s = [1]

def foo():
  global i
  i += 1
  print i

def goo():
  s.append(2)
  print s
```

I want to know why PyIntObject is set locally by default while others objects not?

Thanks!

Comment: It's rather bizarre that you know about PyIntObjects, but not the scope rules.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Python, why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/in-python-why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `global i` there unless you intend to bind `i` to some other object. The same would apply to `s`. Since they are both bound to immutable objects, you can't change their "value" without binding them to a new object.

So this is ok

```
def foo():
    print i
```

But here you need to use the global keyword

```
def foo():
    global i
    i = 'world'
```

Likewise for s. The assignment means you nee the `global` keyword there

```
def goo():
    global s
    s = 2
```

Of course you can alter mutable objects, so often you'd not need to make them global

```
i = [1]

def foo():
    i[0] = 2
```

But you'd still need to make `i` global there if you want to rebind it to a different object