# Delete a root from a tree in python

Tags: python

I am implementing a deletion of a node from a binary search tree in python.
I got stuck in an edge case.
Consider next code:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
root = Node(5)
root.right = Node(10)
```

How to implement a function that deletes the root.
I do not want the function return new root.
In C++ I can modify pointer to make root point to its child, however in python variables are  [labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/575196/1082727) essentially. Is it even possible to do in python?

Comment: Why not `root = root.right`?

Comment: I'm pretty confused what you're trying to do here ... Can you try to explain it better?

Comment: @Mephy I assume the OP has other references to `root` they also want updated.

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not want function to return new root"  What do you want to happen to the reference to root after it is deleted?

Comment: @Mephy Yes, this will work. What if there is only one root, without children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed no way to replace `root` and have it replaced wherever the instance pointed to by the name `root` appears.

The only way to achieve what you want is to mutate `root` to duplicate the child node.

```
def delete(node, inheritLeft=True):
    child = node.left if inheritLeft else node.right
    node.value = child.value
    node.left = child.left
    node.right = child.right
```

(Obviously you might want to do something smarter regarding choosing which node to inherit).

Comment: Good answer. What if there is only one root without children?

Comment: @msh That depends on what behaviour you want in your system. Maybe you want to set all the values to `None`, or have some other special flag for a null node. There is no way to replace the overall node with `None`, however, as you can only mutate, not replace the value and have your changes affect other names.

Comment: I just want to implement deletion in binary search tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion . In case when there is only one root, the algorithm does not do anything.

Comment: @msh In which case, you can just do nothing here.