# List manipulation (mutable or not)?

Tags: python, list, mutable

I have this snippet of code:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1
list1 = [4, 5, 6]

print(list2)
print(list1)
```

Which results in the following output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Why is `list2` not still pointed to `[4, 5, 6]`?  I was under the impression that, since lists are mutable, the change would affect both `list1` and `list2`, since in RAM both lists are pointed to the same sequence of items.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/575196/395760 In fact it pretty much answers the question if you replace "pass to a function" with "assign to a variable".

Answer (score 4):

I have added the reason as *comments* in the code :

```
# list1 variable points to the memory location containing [1, 2, 3]
list1 = [1, 2, 3] 
# list2 variable made to point to the memory location pointed to by list1 
list2 = list1    
# list1 variable made to point to the memory location containing 
# a new list [4, 5, 6], list2 still pointing to [1, 2, 3] 
list1 = [4, 5, 6] 

print(list2) # list2 prints [1, 2, 3]
print(list1) # list1 prints [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Perhaps, I shouldn't have gone with inline comments, they are tough to read!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks a lot Paddy, Your edit saved ma day! 3 votes in 6 mins (none from 35 mins) Seems impossible? Not anymore .... Thanks again!!!

Comment: No worries, the invoice is in the post ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'll go through the lines one by one:

```
# Define a list [1, 2, 3] and save it into list1 variable
list1 = [1, 2, 3]

# Define list2 to be equal to list1 (that is, list2 == list1 == [1, 2, 3])
list2 = list1

# Create a new list [4, 5, 6] and save it into list1 variable
# Notice, that this replaces the existing list1!!
list1 = [4, 5, 6]

# Print list2, which still points to the original list [1, 2, 3]
print(list2)

# Print the new list1, [4, 5, 6] that is
print(list1)
```

However, this:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1
list1.append(4)

print(list2)
print(list1)
```

Will output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Since we are editing the `list1` (and therefore `list2`, they **are** mutable), not creating a new list and saving it under the variable name `list1`

The keyword here is **create a new list**, so you're not editing `list1` in your example, you're actually changing the name `list1` to point to a whole different list.

Answer (score 3):

Lists **are** mutable. However, the line:

```
list1 = [4, 5, 6]
```

**does not** mutate the list object previously referenced by `list1`, it creates a **brand new list object**, and switches the `list1` identifier to reference the new one. You can see this by looking at object IDs:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2 = list1
>>> id(list1)
4379272472
>>> id(list2)
4379272472  # both reference same object
>>> list1 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> id(list1)
4379279016  # list1 now references new object
>>> id(list2)
4379272472  # list2 still references previous object
```