# Python updating int and list with function

Tags: python

I am new at Python and wonder how a function can act on variables and collections. I do not understand why my update_int function cannot update an int whereas update_list can?

```
def update_int(i):
  i = 1

i = 0
update_int(i)
print i
```

returns 0

```
def update_list(alist):
  alist[0] = 1

i = [0]
update_list(i)
print i
```

returns [1]

Comment: to change variable in function you can use `global i` , without passing it to the function 

and it doesn't work because with variable you work on "copy" of that variable

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Python, why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/in-python-why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller)

Answer (score 3):

Because changing a [mutable](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) object like `list` within a function can impact the caller and its not True for [immutable](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) objects like `int`.

So when you change the `alist` within your list you can see the changes out side of the functions too.But note that it's just about in place changing of passed-in mutable objects, and creating new object (if it was mutable) doesn't meet this rules!!

```
>>> def update_list(alist):
...   alist=[3,2]
... 
>>> l=[5]
>>> update_list(l)
>>> l
[5]
```

For more info read [Naming and Binding In Python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

Comment: @VigneshKalai I explain a bit in answer for more info read https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding

Comment: Thanks @kasra this itself provided a lot of insights