# Python: how to reference values in a def

Tags: python, reference, return

As a very basic example of what I want to do, I want to update the values 1 and 2, after running them through the example method. Like how you would use ref for Java.

```
def example(value1, value2):
    value1 += 2
    value2 += 4

value1 = 0
value2 = 0

example(value1, value2)
print(str(value1))
print(str(value1))
```

Comment: I recommend looking up functions in the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/in-python-why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller) you need to `return` them

```
def example(value1, value2):
    value1 += 2
    value2 += 4
    return (value1, value2)

>>> value1 = 0
>>> value2 = 0
>>> value1, value2 = example(value1, value2)
>>> print(value1, value2)
2 4
```

You can only do what you are asking if the passed-in type is mutable, which an `int` is not.

Comment: Well I needed the value as an int, so I've just repeated the code in my project. Thanks for helping :)