# Function parameter in python and value change

Tags: arrays, numpy

I'm new to Python. From my friends, I learned that in python, parameter passing to a function is similar to call-by-reference in C++. But after some testing with NumPy, I saw some behaviors I cannot easily understand.

As an example, I made the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np

def InitArray(x):
  x = np.arange(0, 5)

def ChangeValue(x):
  x[2] = 4

def main():
  x = np.array([1, 2, 3]) 
  print x
  InitArray(x)
  print x
  ChangeValue(x)
  print x

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

My expectation is after calling InitArray, the array 'x' should have changed to `np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])`, but it turns out that it's not.

But when I call ChangeValue(x), the value is actually changed. So, the following is the result.

```
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3]
[1 2 4]
```

What I don't understand is why the value didn't become `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` after calling InitArray?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Python, why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/in-python-why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller)

Answer (score 3):

I always think of it like pass-by-reference, but assignment in Python is not like assignment in other languages, either.  It is merely binding a reference together with an object.  But that reference can be unbound from that object and bound to a different one.

When you do:

```
def InitArray(x):
  x = np.arange(0, 5)
```

You are rebinding the local variable x to a different value.  But you could have mutated it.  Let me give you a non-numpy example:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     x[3] = 4
...     x = [5, 5, 5]
... 
>>> x = [0] * 20
>>> x
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> foo(x)
>>> x
[0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The rebinding operator is similar to changing what a pointer points to in C.

Answer (score 0):

In `ChangeValue` you are accessing `x` at a specific point in memory. Whereas with `InitArray` you are essentially destroying `x` at the local scope and reassigning it within the function and then not returning the modified `x`.