# Passing list-type argument to function in Python

Tags: python, local-variables

I know that normally argument passed to functions by references. That means to me if I refer an argument to a function and inside that function I change it, the change will apply to the original variable too. In the other word:

```
>>> l1 = [0,]
>>> def f1(l):
    l[0] += 1


>>> l1
[0]
>>> f1(l1)
>>> l1
[1]
>>>
```

Q1: Why immutable types, acts different?

```
>>> s1 = "0"
>>> def f2(s):
    s += "1"


>>> s1
'0'
>>> f2(s1)
>>> s1
'0'
>>>
```

I think that if the argument is mutable, the it change itself, otherwise a new variable will created inside the method locally with the same name, and the changes will not apply to the outside variable. Am I right?

---

When I used arguments with default values, those arguments are defined in the function call as local variables in stack, right? An on return of that function, they became unavailable.

So, let see an snippet:

```
>>> def f3(i , l=list()):
    l.append(i)
    print l


>>> f3(1)
[1]
>>> f3(1)
[1, 1]
>>>
```

Q2: Why I receive `[1, 1]` instead of a single `[1]` in the second call? Doesn't Python define the local input arguments on the call of function repeatedly?

Comment: [In Python, why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/575337/2301450)

Comment: Please don't put 2 questions into one.