# Python: why the object is not modified by the function?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I am trying to understand when we can modify a variable used in a function.
In the example below, the object bound to `x` is not modified by `f` as we can see in the output. I don't understand why.
From my understanding, when we do `x.append(4)` in `f`, we modify the object bound to the name `x`. But it seems that it is not the case, given the output. Where is my error?:

Am i missing something with global variables vs local variables?

Is there a copy of the object which is done when we call `f`?

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/in-python-why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller). However the conclusion was not clear for me and it didn't help me to understand where I was wrong.

```
def f(x):
    x = [0,1,2,3]
    x.append(4)
    print('In f():', x)

x = [0,1,2,3]
print('Before:', x)
f(x)
print('After :', x)
```

Output

```
Before: [0, 1, 2, 3]
In f(): [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
After : [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `x = [0,1,2,3]` - you do that **inside the function** too. Delete that line and you'll see the argument value *does* get modified if you don't immediately shadow it with a new object. *"we modify the object bound to the name `x`"* - yes, but you've explicitly bound a different object.

Comment: You are not modifying the `x` from the global namespace but the newly created one in the functions namespace. They are different objects even that they have the same name (in different namespaces).

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: why would your function take x, then to just to redefine it?

Comment: Thank you jonsharpe and Klaus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this statement:

```
x = [0,1,2,3]
```

Inside the body of `f`, it creates a brand new `x` just for that `f`.

You can check this yourself by printing the `id` of the variable:

```
>>> def f(x):
...    x = [0,1,2,3]
...    x.append(4)
...    print('Inside f, x is: {} with id: {}'.format(x, id(x)))
...
>>> x = [0,1,2,3]
>>> print('{} {}'.format(x, id(x)))
[0, 1, 2, 3] 139706697083592
>>> f(x)
Inside f, x is: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] with id: 139706697093064
```

Now, to use the `x` from outside of `f`, just get rid of the assignment operation:

```
>>> def f2(x):
...     x.append(4)
...     print('Inside f2, x is: {} with id: {}'.format(x, id(x)))
...
>>> print('{} {}'.format(x, id(x)))
[0, 1, 2, 3] 139706697083592
>>> f2(x)
Inside f2, x is: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] with id: 139706697083592
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You'll not that the id is the same, and more importantly, the value of `x` outside the function has also changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of x try this:

```
def f(x):
    x.append(4)
    print('In f():', x)

x = [0,1,2,3]
print('Before:', x)
f(x)
print('After :', x)
```

By doing so you will pass x to the function and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring x in your function. The x inside your function is not the same x outside your function. Furthermore, you cannot call the x from inside your function. So in order to make your code work, you need to delete the x from inside your function.For more information go see [Python variable scope](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/)