# Why do I explicitly need to .copy() a numpy array/list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, copying

Why do I have to `.copy()` a numpy array (or list, though those don't have `.copy()` but make for a good minimal example) when I want to get an independend copy of it, while I don't have to do so with a variable? **What's the reason for this behaviour?**

E.g. setting `a = 1` and `b = a` and then setting `b = 2` does not change `a`, whereas `a=([0])`, `b = a` and `b[0]=1` also changes `a`.

**Edit:**

It appears that this is a very common issue/question that can be asked in various ways, so I couldn't find it. For a quick *"I just need to understand what's happening so that I can move on"* I guess the answer (and the answers to the other same/similar questions) are good enough. For a better understanding I guess [this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) link provided by @chthonicdaemon in the comments seems like a good starting point for me.

**longer Background**

In many situations I have to set up a numpy array with some starting values which then gets filled with other values while my program runs. I.e.

```
logger = np.zeros(5)
#various things happen
logger[0] = 1
#more stuff happens
logger[3] = 1
```

you get the idea.

But often it is desirable to have the base array preserved in order to be able to compare the results to it, so I just set up the base first and then make copies from it. So I would expect that I simply could set it up like this:

```
base = np.zeros(5)
logger = base
logger[0] = 1
```

so that

```
In [1]:base
Out[1]:array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
In [2]:logger
Out[2]:array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

However with the above array, they stay "connected", so that I get

```
In [1]:base
Out[1]:array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

I can fix that by explicitly using

```
logger = base.copy()
```

but I'm wondering why I have to.

Comment: integers, strings and tuples for example are *immutable* they can't be modified after their creation, lists, sets and numpy arrays are *mutable* they can be changed

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/in-python-why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller) is exactly the same issue, just with a function thrown into the mix. The difference is that you two different things with those variables. Changing the value of a *variable* with an assignment like `logger = foo` is something completely different than modifying an *object* with something like `logger[0] = 1`.

Comment: [This](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) is the best explanation of how Python names work that I know of.

Comment: If you have ever learnt C/C++, you can easily understand this as it is just implemented like pointer.

Comment: `logger` and `base` reference the same object.

Comment: I guess I begin to see what's happening/why. Rather confusing that `=` has different meanings, depending on what I apply it to.

Comment: I don't like that dupe. It doesn't address the difference between `foo = bar` and `foo[0] = bar`. This question is asking why two different operations do two different things, not why an assignment doesn't make a copy.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python That talks about plain `list`, but it's the same principle. And for a shorter article with cute diagrams that discusses the same stuff as that Ned Batchelder article, but from a slightly different angle, please see [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists (and numpy arrays) are **mutuable** objects. *str and int* are **immutable.** Immutable objects can't be changed once created, so:

```
a = 1
b = a
```

Both points to an immutable object of int, which value is 1. When you change b, you assign it a new value:

```
b = 3
```

Now `b` points to a different object, while `a` pointer hasn't changed.

Now, lists are mutuable. That means, you can change these objects after they are created.

```
alist = list((1, 2, 3))
newlist = alist

alist == newlist
True
```

`alist` now is a reference to a list object. The list object is just a container of references to the actual objects. So when I assign a new variable the value of `alist`, I just create another variable pointing to the same container object.

*Manipulating one object affects both variables, because they refer to the same container object.*

What copy does is making a new copy of the list, including a copy of the references. (sometimes refered as deepcopy). This creates a new container object, hence when changing one of the lists - the other one doesn't change.

Comment: "Now, lists are immutable." Shouldn't that be "mutable"?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the object is mutable or not. What matters is what you do with that object. If you don't modify a list, you don't need to copy it. The difference lies in `foo = x` vs `foo[0] = x`, that is, modifying the *variable* vs modifying the *object*.

Comment: @JC_CL Thanks for pointing it out, I fixed it

Comment: @Aran-Fey your last sentence nails it. I couldn't state it better: modifying the variable vs the object.