# mutability of function parameters

Tags: python

I guess the function parameter does not change the original variable. For e.g.

```
x=10

def mycal(someval):
    someval = someval * 2
    return someval
```

It will return 20 if I call the function:

```
mycal(x)
20
```

But the value of x is still 10:

```
x
10
```

Now why does the theta value has changed to 3.7 and 3.2 when I run this code?

```
import numpy as np

X = 2 * np.random.rand(100,1)
y = 4 +3 * X+np.random.randn(100,1)

def predict_func(slope,intercept,x_test):
    pred = ((np.dot(x_test, slope)) + intercept)        
    return pred

def mse_calc(prediction, y_test):
    error = np.mean((prediction - y_test)**2)
    return error

def grad_descent(s_theta, l_rate, tolerance, iter_val, x_train, y_train):

    n_data = len(x_train)
    bias = np.ones((n_data,1))
    s_intercept = s_theta[0]
    s_slope = s_theta[1:]
    prediction = predict_func(s_slope, s_intercept, x_train)
    error =  mse_calc(prediction, y_train)
    x_train_b = np.append(bias, x_train, axis = 1) 

    for i in range(iter_val):
        int_theta = [0 for i in range(len(x_train[0]) + 1)]
        n_pt = float(len(x_train))

        prediction = predict_func(s_slope, s_intercept, x_train)

        int_theta = 2 / n_pt * np.dot(x_train_b.T, (prediction - y_train))       
        s_theta -=  l_rate * int_theta

    s_intercept = s_theta[0]
    s_slope = s_theta[1:]
    prediction = predict_func(s_slope, s_intercept, x_train)
    final_error = mse_calc(prediction, y_train)

    return  s_theta, final_error


theta = np.zeros((len(X[0]) + 1, 1))
tolerance = 0.0001
l_rate = 0.01
iterations = 5000

print (theta)

grad_theta, grad_error  = grad_descent(theta, l_rate, tolerance, iterations, X, y)

print (theta)
```

I expect the theta value to be still 0 while grad_theta should be 3.7

---

In the following example, the first one is redefining the variable while the next 2 are pointers and appending mutable object.

```
some_list = some_list + [2]
some_list.append(2)
some_list += [2]
```

+= is close the option 2 and not option 1 as I expected.

What are += and -= any way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller-but-not-oth)

Answer (score 2):

```
someval = someval * 2
```

This redefines `someval`. After redefinition `x` and `someval` are no longer referring to the same object, so this doesn't modify `x`.

```
s_theta -=  l_rate * int_theta
```

This mutates `s_theta`, doesn't redefine it, so this will affect the value of `theta` too since `s_theta` and `theta` are still referring to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

That is not completly true, in python some objects are mutable and some other are not. For example, `strings` and `ints` are inmutable, but `list` or `dictionaries` are mutable, check this example:

```
>>> x = []
>>> def add(l, v):
...     l.append(v)
... 
>>> add(x, 5)
>>> add(x, 5)
>>> x
[5, 5]
```

In your case, `theta` is a numpy array, hence it is mutable, that is why it changes.

Comment: Well not quite... if you redefine a dict or a list, you'll have the same effect even if lists and dicts are mutable. The key point here is that redefining and mutating are fundamentally different things...

Answer (score 1):

This is idea about mutable, the article of [Mohan on Medium](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747) explicitly explain what is mutable in python.

List object, however, is mutable so you should consider it like pointer, which still pointing to same element.

Thus, you may have a function like

```
a = []
def change():
  a.append(1)
change()
print(a) #[1]
```

But

```
a = 0
def change():
  a += 1
change()
print(a) #0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try this same procedure with a `list`, you'll see similar behavior with `theta`:

```
def myfunc(somelist):
    for i in range(len(somelist)):
        somelist[i] = 3

mylist = [0]*8
myfunc(mylist)
# mylist is now [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
```

This is because in the function for your `int`, the python interpreter creates a new var local to the function, it isn't tracking a reference count to that `int`, because `int`s are immutable objects. However, `lists` are mutable, and so reference counting must be incorporated otherwise you can wind up with very unsafe behavior.

With this in mind, when you pass your list into a function, it is mutable and will be edited by the function that holds the reference to that variable. The `int`, however, is immutable, and therefore another copy is created as it goes through function scopes

Answer (score 1):

Numpy operates differently for `=` and `-=` operators. Check the following code snippet.

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
  x = x - 1
  return x

def g(x):
  x -= 1
  return x

a = np.array([1,2])

b = f(a)
print (a, b)
>>> [1 2] [0 1]

c = g(a)
print (a, c)
>>> [0 1][0 1]
```