# Function in Python is treating list like a global variable. How to fix this?

Tags: python, search, binary, global

I'm not sure why `l` would be modified by the `find()` function. I thought since I'm using a different variable in another function, `l` would not be modified by the function since it's not global.

I made sure it wasn't an error in the code by copy and pasting `l = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]` before every print statement, and it returned the right outputs, meaning `l` is being changed by the function. I also removed the main function from the main and basically made it outright global, but it still gave the original bad results.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with my understanding of Python since I'm a beginner in it and I'm coming from Java.

Here's the code and results:

```
def find(list, user):
    while True:
        n = len(list)
        half = int(n/2)
        if n == 1:
            if user != list[0]:
                return "Bad"
            else:
                return "Good"
        elif user == list[half]:
            return "Good"
        elif user > list[half]:
            del list[0:half]
        elif user < list[half]:
            del list[half:n]
        print(list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
    print(find(l, 5))  # should print Bad
    print(find(l, 10))  # should print Good
    print(find(l, -1))  # should print Bad
    print(find(l, 2))  # should print Good
```

but it returns with this

```
[2, 4]
[4]
Bad
Bad
Bad
Bad
```

Comment: `del ...` is modifying the original list since you are not passing in a copy of the list but rather a reference to the original list itself. Simplest fix is to pass in a copy of the list: `find(l[:], 5)`

Comment: why do you use `print(list)` inside `find()` ? shouldn't be some `return text`.

Comment: You should go for indices based approach and not use `del`.

Comment: The variable `list` is just a reference to the original list `l`. So when you modify the variable `list`,  the original list also gets modified. Also please avoid using `list` as variable names as they are keywords in python. If you wanna modify the list just make a copy of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read this question at first. [why can a function modified some arguments while not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller-but-not-oth).

Let me rewrite your code for clarification.

```py
def find(li, el):
    # li is a list, el is an integer
    # do something using li and el

if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = [1,2,3,4]
    e = 2
    find(l, e)
```

The function `find` received two objects as parameters, one is `li` and the other is `el`. In `main`, we defined two objects, a list, we called it `l`, and an integer, we called it `e`. Then these two objects was passed to `find`. It should be clear that it is these two objects that passed to the function, not the name. Then your `find` function has access to this object, called `l` in main, while called `li` in `find`. So when you change `li` in `find`, `l` changed as well.

Hope that answers your question. And to fix this, check `deepcopy`.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments in Python are passed by assignment. https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference

In your case, that means that the `list` parameter of your `find` function is assigned the exact same list you pass in as the argument `l`. So, when you modify `list` (which is a very bad name since it shadows Python's `list` keyword), you also modify `l`, since no copy of the original was made.

You could use `copy()` to pass in a copy, but I think you would do well to reconsider the function as a whole, since it currently has many, many issues and you're likely to end up with a solution that won't suffer from having the original list passed in.