# How to declare an array as a function parameter in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have declared an empty list. I want to store in that one some strings from a text file. If I am doing without creating `TXT_to_PList` it is working smoothly. But using `TXT_to_PList` length of `deTrimis` array will be `0`. Why?

```
deTrimis = []

def TXT_to_PList(fileName,array):
    with open(fileName) as f:
        array = f.read().splitlines()
TXT_to_PList('strings.txt',deTrimis)
print (len(deTrimis))
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you *actually* interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that empty list at all:

```
def TXT_to_PList(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()

deTrimis = TXT_to_PList('strings.txt')
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify function argument by assignment, change it to:

```
array.extend(f.read().splitlines())
```

see more info here: [Why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller-but-not-oth)