# using a function to update one of its argument permanently

Tags: python, function

How can I create a function that updates the value of one of its arguments? Consider the following example:

```
def f(x,b):
    b+=1
    return x*b

b=4
a=f(1,b)
print a
print b
```

The update of `b` is valid only inside the function, but `b` keeps its original value after the function has been used. Of course, in this case I could just solve the problem by returning also `b` and then using `a,b=f(1,b)` but I do not want to do it.

What should I do if I actually want `b` to be updated and change its value without returning it explicitly ?

Comment: Use global variables or switch to C.

Comment: What do you mean by `b`? Do you specifically care about the *global* `b` (that you initially set with `b = 4`)? Or do you want the function to have a *separate, yet persistent* `b` value?

Comment: You can't update the value of `4`; it's always 4. *Inside* `f`, it has a local variable set to 4, but it has no idea that the 4 came from a global variable.

Comment: For some context, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196

Comment: Can you update your example for a second call to `f` and what you'd expect to happen?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I specifically care about the global `b`.

Comment: Then don't pass it as a parameter, and use `global b` to gain write access to it in the function.

Comment: Related: [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/4518341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to hold state which is a strong indication that a class is needed. I assume that second and following calls to `f` should use the saved `b` variable. Here is a class that keeps that state and uses a magic method to make it callable:

```
class F:

    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

    def __call__(self, x):
        self.b += 1
        return x * self.b

b = 4
f = F(b)
a = f(1)
print(a, f.b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't support call by reference. There are only ugly workarounds like e.g.

```
def f(x,b):
    b[0]+=1
    return x*b[0]

b=[4]
a=f(1,b)
print a
print b[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

To manage global states of your variables, consider using classes instead. Your function only modifies the value of `b` locally to your function. If you don't want to have all of your code inside a class, but only a part of it, and keep the `b` value, make `@classmethods` instead. Here is an example you may try:

```py
class Store:
    b = [4]

    @classmethod
    def f(cls, x):
        cls.b[0] += 1
        return x * cls.b[0]

Store.f(1) # -> 5
Store.f(1) # -> 6
Store.f(1) # -> 7
```

Please note, this changes how you can call into the function, as `b`, or in this case, the `cls.b`, is in the namespace of the class. You can get/set/reset the `b` value by setting on the class directly, just like this: `Store.b = [42]`.

Answer (score 1):

Functions can have attributes which can be assigned  internally. Those attributes can retain the values you want the function to hold throughout multiple calls.

```
def f(x,b=None):
    try:
    f.b+=1
except AttributeError:
    f.b=b # first pass (initialize the attribute) 
return x*f.b

b=4
a=f(1,b) # initialize 
print (f(2))
print (f(2))
print (f(2))
```

Output:

```
10
12
14
```