# Python: How do I change a global variable when it is a paramter inside a function?

Tags: python, variables, global-variables

For example:

```
x = {'a':1, 'b':2}
y = {}

# only requirement: x and y has to be parameters of function foo
def foo(x,y):
    '''
    How do I switch the two variables inside this function without scope issues?
    '''

print('x =', x)
print('y =', y)
```

Result:

```
x = {}
y = {'a':1, 'b':2}
```

I tried putting `global x, y` and putting `x,y = y,x` inside the function but got this error as expected because they are already global:

```
SyntaxError: name 'x' is parameter and global
# Same thing happens for y
```

Comment: rename paramters, dont use `x`, `y` due to it's already represent global variable

Comment: x and y has to be the parameters of function foo, sorry forget to mention that.

Comment: I mean you can rename `x`, `y` to other names, didn't mean to remove them, don't make paramters name as the same as global variable cause it will raise `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with global variables, don't take args ;-)

```
def foo():
  global x,y
  x,y = y,x
```

Enlightening on my alternate idea

```
def foo(x,y):
  return [y,x]

myList = foo(x,y)
x,y = myList[0], myList[1]
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that x and y has to be parameters of function foo.

Comment: Then make the function return a list like `return [x,y]` after swap, then assign to variable and later get into x,y !! Man it's easy

Comment: Sorry I am still learning. I do not get it. Can you visualize the steps for me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {'a':1, 'b':2}
y = {}

def foo():
    global x,y  #bring global variable in func scope
    x,y = y,x #swaps variable variable values

def foo1():
    globals()['x'] = {'a':1, 'b':2}  #update value of global variable in func
    globals()['y'] = {}

#method1
foo()
print(x,y)

#method2
x = {'a':1, 'b':2}
y = {}
foo1()
print(x,y)
```

Both functions will work.

If you want to send the variable as args:
check Pythons concept of mutability of variables.
Additionally check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller-but-not-oth)