# Python some assertion errors failing

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort a list in order from odd to even but when I pass it through and assert statements it only works on a few assert statements. Looking at the print output everything should be working as its in the right order from odd to even but its failing the assert statements.

```
 def oddsBeforeEvens(theList):
    odd = []
    even = []
    for x in theList:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            even.append(x)
        else: 
            odd.append(x)
    theList = odd + even


aList = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -6, -7]
oddsBeforeEvens(aList)
print(aList)  # Debugging print
assert(aList[0] % 2 != 0)  # odd integer
assert(aList[1] % 2 != 0)
assert(aList[2] % 2 != 0)
assert(aList[3] % 2 != 0)
assert(aList[4] % 2 != 0)  # odd integer
assert(aList[5] % 2 == 0)  # even integer
assert(aList[6] % 2 == 0)
assert(aList[7] % 2 == 0)
assert(aList[8] % 2 == 0)  # even integer
```

Comment: Your function doesn't actually modify the input.  It only makes a local variable.  The line with a "# Debugging print" comment should have made that obvious ...

Answer (score 2):

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/575887/3365922):

> Any time you see varname =, you're creating a new name binding within the function's scope. Whatever value varname was bound to before is lost within this scope.

So when you did `theList = odd + even` inside `oddsBeforeEvens` it doesn't "pointing" to the global `aList` anymore, `aList` remains unchanged. You can fix it this way:

```
 def oddsBeforeEvens(theList):
    ...
    return odd + even

...
aList = oddsBeforeEvens(aList)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you assign a value to `theList`.  Whenever you assign a value to a variable in a function, Python will assume that the variable is local to that function unless you explicitly state otherwise.

So, when you write

```
theList = odd + even
```

Python creates a variable local to that function called `theList`.  The original `theList` variable reminds untouched.  So, when you assert that `aList[1] %2 != 0`, that fails because that element is still 0.

It would be better to return the new list from the function like

```
def oddsBeforeEvens(theList):
    odd = []
    even = []
    for x in theList:
        if x%2 == 0:
            even.append(x)
        else:
            odd.append(x)
    return odd + even
```