# Swapping name using function in python

Tags: python

why doesn't this code does not return the variable I expected ?
I know this is not an efficient of doing it just curious what is the problem for this code

```
def format_name(f_name, t_name):
   switch_name = ""
   switch_name = f_name
   f_name = t_name
   t_name = switch_name

a = "Cinn"
b = "Alex"
format_name(a,b)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: what do you expect to happen? `format_name` never returns anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller-but-not-oth)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you don't need a function for such a simple task use this syntax:

```py
a = "Cinn"
b = "Alex"
a, b = b, a
```

If you insist on a function then just wanted to add a tiny little trick to @Robo's answer, you can directly store the values in a and b with tuple unpacking and not have to use indices.

```py
# @Robo's code
def format_name(f_name, t_name):
   return t_name, f_name

a = "Cinn"
b = "Alex"
a, b = format_name(a,b) # tuple unpacking
```

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because you've declared the variables a and b, and after calling the function you've printed a and b which have remained unchanged.

You need to return `f_name` and `t_name` in the function, and then print the returned things. So, a working solution would look like this:

```
def format_name(f_name, t_name):
   switch_name = ""
   switch_name = f_name
   f_name = t_name
   t_name = switch_name
   return f_name, t_name

a = "Cinn"
b = "Alex"
formatted = format_name(a,b)
print(formatted[0])
print(formatted[1])
```

But this uses way too much storage than is required, so just returning `t_name` and `f_name` in order, instead of `f_name` and t_name` will do everything better.

```
def format_name(f_name, t_name):
   return t_name, f_name

a = "Cinn"
b = "Alex"
formatted = format_name(a,b)
a, b = formatted
print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: Skip the function and use `a,b = b,a`.

Comment: Probably, but @codecinn requires a function