# Different behaviors of a Python list in a recursive function

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion

I'm learning to write recursive functions in Python, and find a list can have different behaviors depending on whether I choose to use `res.append(new_loc)` or `res + [new_loc]`.

For example,

```
def solver(counter,res):
    
    print("Entering the solver:",res)
    if len(res) >= 4:return 
    counter += 1 

    res.append(counter) 

    solver(counter,res)
    print("inner solver returned:",res)
    counter += 1 
    res.append('haha%i'% counter)
   
solver(0,[])
```

This gives me the output

```
Entering the solver: []
Entering the solver: [1]
Entering the solver: [1, 2]
Entering the solver: [1, 2, 3]
Entering the solver: [1, 2, 3, 4]
inner solver returned: [1, 2, 3, 4]
inner solver returned: [1, 2, 3, 4, 'haha5']
inner solver returned: [1, 2, 3, 4, 'haha5', 'haha4']
inner solver returned: [1, 2, 3, 4, 'haha5', 'haha4', 'haha3']
```

The list `res` acts like a recorder, and saves all the values.

However, if I change the `solver` function a little bit

```
def solver(counter,res):
    
    print("Just entering the solver:",res)
    if len(res) >= 4:return 
    counter += 1 
    
    solver(counter,res+[counter])
    
    print("inner solver returned:",res)
    counter += 1 
    res.append('haha%i'% counter)
       
solver(0,[])
```

The output becomes

```
Just entering the solver: []
Just entering the solver: [1]
Just entering the solver: [1, 2]
Just entering the solver: [1, 2, 3]
Just entering the solver: [1, 2, 3, 4]
inner solver returned: [1, 2, 3]
inner solver returned: [1, 2]
inner solver returned: [1]
inner solver returned: []
```

In this case, why `res.append('haha%i'% counter)` is not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller-but-not-oth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res + [counter]` creates a new list and you are not assigning that to `res`, just passing it as a method parameter. Even though `res` is mutable, this operation does not mutate the original object.

Each recursive method call has a separate list, which is why the "entering" print statement is fine, but the "inner" statement doesn't have the correct values. The modifications were not passed back up the chain.

On the other hand, using `append()` or `extend()` will mutate the original object. As seen in the docs about [Mutable Sequence operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), `res += [counter]` would be the equivalent to `extend()`, because it reassigns the new list to `res`.

An easy way to visualize this is to test the value of your original list after the call:

```py
inp_list = []
solver(0, inp_list)
print(inp_list)
```

Output 1 will be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 'haha5', 'haha4', 'haha3', 'haha2']` because all your methods modify the same list, the one that you originally passed. This will work with `append()`, `extend()` and `+=`.

Output 2 will be `['haha2']`, because only your initial `solver()` call modifies this list. The recursive calls do not affect it at all.