# Why can't I change a variable through a method in Python?

Tags: python, function, indexing

I can change an element of a list through the following code:

```
def myFunction(x):
    x[0] = 2
    
myList = [4,5,6]
myFunction(myList)
print(myList)  # ==> outputs [2,5,6] (myList[0] is changed to '2' through the function).
```

But I don't understand why I cannot change a variable using the same code:

```
def myFunction(x):
    x = 2
    
myNumber = 6
myFunction(myNumber)
print(myNumber)  # ==> outputs 6 (myNumber is not changed to '2' through the function).
```

Comment: Required reading: [Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) and [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/4014959

Comment: Does that ↑, answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
def myFunction(x):
    x = 2
    return x

myNumber = 6
myNumber = myFunction(myNumber)
print(myNumber)
```

You can't change the variable the way you wrote. Instead you can return a value and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

This method of changing variables globally is not the best way to solve the problem. However; you can do this:

```py
def myFunction(x):
    globals()[x] = 2


myNumber = 6
# Must pass variable name as literal string
myFunction("myNumber")
print(myNumber)
```

Getting a variable as a string is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58451182/14141223)

---

I suggest you do something like this ([to avoid using globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)):

```py
def myFunction():
    return 2


myNumber = 6
myNumber = myFunction()
print(myNumber)
```

---

More specifically, you would do this for lists:

This is the unconventional `global` method (not preferred)

```py
def myFunction(x):
    globals()[x][1] = 2


myNumbers = [0, 0, 0]
# Must pass variable name as literal string
myFunction("myNumbers")
print(myNumbers)
```

And the preferred method:

```py
def myFunction():
    return 2


myNumbers = [0, 0, 0]
myNumbers[1] = myFunction()
print(myNumbers)
```

Comment: But how am I able to change an element of a list in such a way that doesn't work when reassigning a variable?

Comment: Like your first piece of code in the question?

Comment: Yes, like the first piece of code in the OP.

Comment: I'll edit the post

Comment: I can already reassign an element of a list using the first piece of code in the OP.
My question is:
This code doesn't work with reassigning variables (and I can understand why that is so).
But this code works when reassigning an element of a list. Why does it work with an element of a list, but not with a variable, for example with a list.

Comment: That answer is a bit of a read. As suggested in the comments, you may find @jarmod's links answer your question

Comment: See [Why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller-but-not-oth).