# How to resolve the scope problem in this particular functions?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am implementing a shuffling algorithm and I need to check how many times I have ti run the algorithm to get the original array. I have tried implementing a while loop and initiating a counter but there is some problem with the scope. The arrays arr and arr2 have equal values. Can someone help?

```
from random import randint, random
from math import floor


def shuffle(the_list):
    amnt_to_shuffle = len(the_list)
    while amnt_to_shuffle > 1:
        i = int(floor(random() * amnt_to_shuffle))
        amnt_to_shuffle -= 1
        the_list[i], the_list[amnt_to_shuffle] = the_list[amnt_to_shuffle], the_list[i]
    return the_list

arr = [i for i in range(1,11)]
original_arr = arr
k = 0

while 1:
    arr2 = shuffle(arr)
    if arr2 == original_arr:
        break
    else:
        shuffle(arr)
        k += 1

print(k)
```

Comment: Do these answer your question? [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment) and [Why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller-but-not-oth)

Comment: To be clear, this problem has nothing to do with scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has only **one** list. `arr`, `original_arr`, `arr2`, ... they are all the *same* list. Your `shuffle` function *mutates* the list it gets as argument. Even though that function returns the list, this *is* the caller's list that it passed as argument, so it is *that* list that is shuffled.

It would be more pythonic to *not* return the list in this `shuffle` function, so to make absolutely clear to the caller that their list is mutated (shuffled) by it. This also means you don't need `arr2`.

Unrelated, but your loop should just have one call to `shuffle`, not two.

The key is to make `original_arr` a new list that is a copy of `arr`. You can do this in several ways, e.g. by slice syntax:

```
original_arr = arr[:]
k = 0

while 1:
    shuffle(arr)
    if arr == original_arr:
        break
    k += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

By writing `original_arr = arr` you copy the pointer of `arr` to `original_arr` hence any change in any one of them will effect the other.

You can import [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to deep copy the list or to use `original_arr = arr[:]`