# Is it correct to manipulate the list and add the elements to the list without using append() within it?

Tags: python

```py
def push(stack:list):
    stack = stack + [2]

stack = []
print(stack)
stack = stack + [1]
print(stack)
push(stack)
print(stack)
```

This is my python code.

I expected the final value of the list to be [1,2], but the result was [1]. I understand that the stack variable in the stack = stack + [2] code in push() is used as a local variable, but I don't know why. Also, I would like to know how to write the code, and how to add elements to a list without using append() inside a function that receives a list as a parameter.

Comment: Can you using extend

Comment: Inside of `push`, `stack` is effectively a *local* variable, so assignments to it do not effect the global `stack`.  See what happens if you change the name of the parameter.

Comment: Why can't you use `append`?

Comment: You are also creating new list each time when doing `stack = stack + [2]`.

Comment: `stack = stack + [2]` makes a **new** list object (containing the contents of the existing list object, and 2), and assigns that object to the local name `stack` within the function. The global name `stack` still refers to the pre-existing list object, which has not changed. To change that existing object, `stack.append(2)`, or `stack.extend([2])`, or `stack += [2]`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller-but-not-oth