# Why empty list to function?

Tags: python-3.x

Why is an empty list passed to the `binary_search` function? After all, it's not really empty.

```py
from typing import List


def binary_search(nums: List[int], item: int):
    print("binary_search nums", nums)
    low = 0
    high = len(nums) - 1

    while low <= high:
        middle = (low + high) // 2

        if nums[middle] == item:
            return middle
        if nums[middle] > item:
            high = middle - 1
        if nums[middle] < item:
            low = middle + 1
    return None


def smallest_find(nums: List[int]):
    smallest = nums[0]
    smallest_index = 0

    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] < smallest:
            smallest = nums[i]
            smallest_index = i
    return smallest_index


def selection_sort(nums: List[int]):
    sorted_nums = []

    for _ in range(len(nums)):
        smallest_index = smallest_find(nums)
        sorted_nums.append(nums.pop(smallest_index))
    return sorted_nums

import random

while True:
    nums = [random.randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(20)]
    item = 24
    if item in nums:
        print(nums)
        print(selection_sort(nums))
        print(binary_search(selection_sort(nums), item))
        break
```

Result:

```
[20, 84, -65, -76, -46, -7, 19, 48, -55, 31, 62, -86, 16, 24, 67, -87, -65, -57, 12, 61]
[-87, -86, -76, -65, -65, -57, -55, -46, -7, 12, 16, 19, 20, 24, 31, 48, 61, 62, 67, 84]
binary_search nums []
None
```

Why is an empty list passed to the `binary_search` function? After all, it's not really empty.

Python 3.8.10

Comment: Your `selection_sort` is modifying the `nums` list passed in by using `nums.pop`.  So after `selection_sort` returns the `nums` list is empty.  Maybe the confusion is because you think `nums` is copied when passed to `selection_sort`?  It isn't copied - lists are passed by reference, so it is the same list being operated on.

Comment: @mkimball But `selection_sort` retern new list (`sorted_nums` instead of `nums`)

Comment: @mkimball I wrote call id `sorted_nums` and `nums` into functio `selection_sort`
Result: `id nums 140228674112576` `id sorted_nums 140228675774464`
```

Comment: Yes, it returns it, and you then print it, but the list you returned is a different one from `nums`, because you created it in `selection_sort`.  If you changed your code to be something like `sorted_list = selection_sort(nums)`, and then `binary_search(sorted_list, item)` you might get results more like you expect.

Comment: To perhaps be more clear: Your current code is calling `selection_sort(nums)` twice.  You will get different results between the first and second time, because you are modifying the input.  The first time you call it you are clearing the contents of `nums`, so that means the second time you call it you are passing the empty list to the sort, and getting an empty list out.

Comment: Think carefully about the logic of the code. How many times does `selection_sort` get called? When `selection_sort` is called, **what happens to** the elements in the input list? Therefore, what will happen if you try to call `selection_sort` again on the same list? If you have written code that should give you the sorted result from an input list, **does it make sense** to modify the input list? Why?

Comment: **If you were expecting** that `sorted_nums.append(nums.pop(smallest_index))` should only change a "local copy" of the list, and not affect the caller's list, **then this is a duplicate**: please see [Why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/575196/). Otherwise, this problem is "resolved in a way that is unlikely to help others", and should be closed as a typo on that basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second call to `selection_sort` actually returns an empty list, that is why `binary_search` is getting an empty list.

The reason is this line:

```
sorted_nums.append(nums.pop(smallest_index))
```

You are `pop`-ing all values from `nums` in your `selection_sort` routine. This is emptying out (and overwriting) input list `nums`

You can avoid this by making a shallow copy of `nums`:

```
from typing import List


def binary_search(nums: List[int], item: int):
    print("binary_search nums", nums)
    low = 0
    high = len(nums) - 1

    while low <= high:
        middle = (low + high) // 2

        if nums[middle] == item:
            return middle
        if nums[middle] > item:
            high = middle - 1
        if nums[middle] < item:
            low = middle + 1
    return None


def smallest_find(nums: List[int]):
    smallest = nums[0]
    smallest_index = 0

    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] < smallest:
            smallest = nums[i]
            smallest_index = i
    return smallest_index


def selection_sort(nums: List[int]):
    sorted_nums = []
    nums_ = nums[:] # shallow copy
    for _ in range(len(nums_)):
        smallest_index = smallest_find(nums_)
        sorted_nums.append(nums_.pop(smallest_index))
    return sorted_nums

import random

while True:
    nums = [random.randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(20)]
    item = 24
    if item in nums:
        print(nums)
        print(selection_sort(nums))
        print(binary_search(selection_sort(nums), item))
        break
```

Output:

```
[41, -59, 38, -50, 25, -62, 58, -81, 7, 24, -93, 41, 92, 3, 65, -61, 47, -54, 72, 65]
[-93, -81, -62, -61, -59, -54, -50, 3, 7, 24, 25, 38, 41, 41, 47, 58, 65, 65, 72, 92]
binary_search nums [-93, -81, -62, -61, -59, -54, -50, 3, 7, 24, 25, 38, 41, 41, 47, 58, 65, 65, 72, 92]
9
```