# replacing object by a dummy before any imports and/or other statements get executed

Tags: python, testing, import

I use USE_DUMMY which if it's set to True then a dummy is created for my module.

The question is: how do I set this variable (from an external module) BEFORE the import and/or other statements get executed?

a.py:

```
USE_DUMMY = False

def unvailable():
    print 'not available'

if USE_DUMMY is True:
    def dummy():
        print "this function is a dummy"
    unavailable = dummy
```

b.py:

```
import a
a.USE_DUMMY = True
```

Here it's already too late to set 
`USE_DUMMY = True`
such that `unavailable()` gets binded by `dummy()` because the definitions were already executed.

If my question is not clear then I could elaborate it further ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by using **builtin**

For more info
[Python: How to make a cross-module variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142545/python-how-to-make-a-cross-module-variable)

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to some other languages, Python's `import` is simply an executable statement. This means that if you want to take some actions before importing some modules, you can simply place code before the relevant `import`.

In other words, if you need to set a global variable before any imports etc, you could place the assignment right at the top of your main script:

```
USE_DUMMIES=True
import abc, xyz
# do stuff
```

If that's not what you're asking, please clarify your question.