# How do I keep a variable the same across different running python scripts?

Tags: python, variables

So I have a variable called "num" which begins with a value of 1 and constantly increases by 1. When I run other python scripts simultaneously, they also use "num" but they of course start from 1 because the num isn't connected to the num in the other scripts. If num is 600 in my first script which has been running for longer, num could be 5 in my other script which hasn't been running for as long.

How can I make it so that if num is 600 in script A, num automatically starts increasing from 600 in script B as soon as I run it? I need the nums to be the same throughout and increase together as one.

Comment: Is saving and reloading from/to a file an option for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple way to pass variables between python scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415298/simple-way-to-pass-variables-between-python-scripts)

Comment: @hlt IIRC, Python has some sort of inter-process concurrency library; especially since that would get around the GIL, which is presumably what you're trying to accomplish. There would be a var-sharing mechanism in place for that.

Comment: @jpaugh Yep, it's `multiprocessing`

Comment: I think I ran across something like this in the standard library, but I don't remember the name of it. Maybe someone else can remember?

Comment: How are starting your Python scripts?

Comment: @Alex Just curious whether you found a solution to the problem. Please update. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The most trivial way to do this is just to use the filesystem as a synchronised variable store. It is not elegant, but it can be achieved as in a quick and dirty way with two scripts:

Script one:

```
# This is a master script that starts everything off.
from time import sleep
count = 0
while True:
    with open("myfile.txt","w+") as f:
        print>>f,count
    print "Script 1 count:",count
    count+=1
    sleep(1)
```

Script two:

```
# This is the script that you start when script one is running
import warnings
from time import sleep

try:
    with open("myfile.txt","r") as f:
        count = int(f.read().strip())
except Exception as error:
    warnings.warn(repr(error))
    count = 0

while True:
    print "Script 2 count:",count
    count+=1
    sleep(1)
```

If you want an elegant solution, you could look into using [sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) to set up a proper message passing system between your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with something called *message passing*. First, start up one process to hold the actual `num` variable, and to synchronize access to it. Then, start up other processes to talk to the first one, and ask it for the current value, then process the next one. (Of course, you'd need to arrange for several *next values* to be processed at the same time.)

With a very quick search, I turned up this. Hope it helps.

http://www.valuedlessons.com/2008/06/message-passing-conccurrency-actor.html