# Python global keyword behavior

Tags: python, global

I am trying to use a global variable across modules by importing the variable and modifying it locally within a function. The code and the output is below. The last output is not what I expected, I thought it should be 15 since it has been already modified in global scope by func3. Can anybody please explain why the last output is still 10.

Thank you!

test2.py

```
myGlobal = 5
def func3():
    global myGlobal
    myGlobal = 15
    print "from 3: ", myGlobal
```

test1.py

```
from test2 import myGlobal, func3

def func1():
    global myGlobal
    myGlobal = 10

def func2():
    print "from 2: ", myGlobal

print "init: ", myGlobal
func1()
func2()
func3()
func2()
```

The outputs:

```
init:  5
from 2:  10
from 3:  15
from 2:  10
```

Comment: `func3` uses itself `myGlobal` not imported `myGlobal` in `test1.py`

Comment: There are no true globals in Python; the module has its own "global" namespace. You can explicitly modify `test2.myGlobal`, but the `global` keyword won't let you rebind names in another module.

Comment: Please, don't write code like that, it is unnecessary, makes the code harder to reason about, and it is harder to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `global` in Python means module level.

So doing:

```
a = 1
```

Has the exact same effect on `a` as:

```
def f():
    global a
    a = 1
f()
```

And in both cases the variable is not shared across modules.

If you want to share a variable across modules, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142545/python-how-to-make-a-cross-module-variable).