# Python 3.x.x one variable spread across multiple .py files

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x

This is not a problem with my code, but rather a general question about Python 3.

Say you had a game, which had 4 parts to it, and the first part (`main.py`) declares a variable
that say, part 2 needs to run itself. Would you be able to declare that variable, then `import part2` (That needs the variable to run smoothly) and have the variable carry on from `main.py` to `part2.py` after importing `part2.py` into `main.py`.

Comment: so whats the problem ? and what you try ?

Comment: My game has 4 parts to it and in main.py has a variable called z. In part2.py when i run it an error points to this:if g > z or g < 0: saying that it is refrenced before assignment. I have tried making it global and that does not work either.

Comment: I have a feeling that you might not know how `import` works. What do you mean with "when I run part2.py"?

Comment: you can not access to a variable from separate file you need to import the function that the variable is in, or ... anyway you need to show your codes !

Comment: related: [Python: How to make a cross-module variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/142545/4279).

Comment: @ J.F. Sebastian, that related help a lot so thanks for putting that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the variable once you can do this.

```
# part2.py

def scream():
 print(sound)  

# part1.py
import part2

if __name__=="__main__":
    part2.sound = "Yoooo"
    part2.scream()

#Output:
Yoooo
```

If you want to be able to change the variable later. [You can create a `property`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#property)
Or simply do this:

```
# part2.py
# gvars is defined later
def scream():
 print(gvars.sound)


# part1.py
import part2

class GameVariables:
    pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    gvars = GameVariables()
    part2.gvars = gvars
    gvars.sound = "Yooo"
    part2.scream()
    gvars.sound = "Whaa"
    part2.scream()

#output
Yooo
Whaa
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example you can try out

**file1.py**

```
import sys
sys.argv = "Yellow" #probably not a really great Idea but should suffice

from file2 import sys as sys2
print "Imported argv from file2",sys2.argv
print "Same thing? ", sys is sys2
```

**file2.py**

```
import sys
print "My argv f2:",sys.argv
```