# How can I pass variables from module to module in Python?

Tags: python

One of the ways I recently started structuring my programming is by having one main file and multiple different appropriately named files that represent different parts of the project that I am working on.

All different Python Files in one folder.

To then use one file I would simply type:

```
import filename
```

This works all well and good, but I noticed that I can't use variables from within another file in that code.

My question is can I import variables, or pass variables from one file to another to make use of them later again?

Comment: To be clear; your asking how to access global variables that exist in one file from another file?

Answer (score 2):

Each file you import is considered to have its own namespace. You can reference anything in that namespace if you prefix it with the module name.

For example, f you have a file like this:

```
# filename.py
foobar = 42
```

You can access `foobar` with `filename.foobar`. For example:

```
import filename
print("foobar is %s" % filename.foobar)
```

Comment: Great! That works, but it doesn't really pass the variable from one location to the next.

Comment: @AlexPanagis: I'm not sure what you mean by "pass the variable". Certainly, you can pass the variable from one function to the next. It's a normal variable, you treat it like any other variable.

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to use `__builtin__` module so that your file main_file.py will contain:

```
print(thing)
```

while your whatever.py will contain:

```
import __builtin__
__builtin__.thing = 1
import main_file
```

More on that: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142545/python-how-to-make-a-cross-module-variable)

Comment: I find this solution hacky.

Comment: And prone to name clashes if two different module use the same name. There is a reason why modules are each in their own namespace.