# importing modules in python from different folders

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have the main script file, let's call it main.py and I have module file which located in subdirectory "module/", let's call it mod.py (module/mod.py)

The directories tree is like this:

```
-main.py

-module/
 |
 |---mod.py
```

Now I have a global variable in main.py, call it "a" and it's equal to 1.
I have a function in mod.py which should print the global variable a.

main.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("module/")
from mod import *

global a
a = 1

print_it()
```

module/mod.py:

```
from main import *

def print_it():
    global a
    print a
```

When I start the main.py script, I get:

> NameError: name 'print_it' is not defined

Why?

Comment: because there is no `main.py` file in `module/` folder

Comment: It won't work. in `main` you import `mod`, in `mod` you import `main` again. And  the problem is here. `mod` wasn't fully imported. And `print_it` is until not created.

Comment: What happens when you change this line in `main.py`: `from mod import *` to `import mod`?

Comment: What version of python do you use ? 3.x or 2.x ? The module import is not the name between these version

Comment: Also, have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142545/python-how-to-make-a-cross-module-variable ?

Comment: try adding `print(__name__)` to your main, you will see `__main__` for the first module being run, and then `main` for the exact copy of it that was imported.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Answer (score 1):

For the import part:
The directories tree should look like this:

```
-main.py

-module/
 |
 |---__init__.py
 |---mod.py
```

The `__init__.py` file can be empty and it is not necessary in 3.x
And if you follow the method to use global as below, you can import your method like that.

```
from mod import print_it
```

---

Instead of using a global variable, you can create a new module Common/Global (whatever you want to name it) as follow:

```
class Common:
    pass

common = Common()
common.a = 0
```

and you import it in your module

```
from Common import common
```

and you will have access to `common.a` in all your module and doesn't pollute your namespace with global variables.

---

Here an example:

Common.py as defined above.

mod.py as follow:

```
from Common import common

def printa():
    print common.a
```

and main.py:

```
from Common import common
from mod import printa

printa()
common.a = 10
printa()
```

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen: It does, with this you can define it with common.a in your main then use it in print_it, that is contained in another module without knowing if the variable in defined or not at first.

Comment: ok... but if it is not defined then you run into problems, and it still doesn't address the issue of `print_a` not being defined.

Comment: _it still doesn't address the issue of `print_a` **the function** not being defined._

Comment: I'm still waiting for the OP to answer which version of python he uses, it is not the same import system between 2.x and 3.x

Comment: [this part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319233/importing-modules-in-python-from-different-folders/37319931?noredirect=1#comment62158293_37319233) of it is the exact same as far as I am concerned. Anyway I agree that some common ground is a good idea hence my upvote, but I really think you could improve this by at least addressing the issue the OP is having instead of simply suggesting a completely different alternative.

Comment: I already asked the question and I am computing the difference between the 2 version, like that the OP could chose. Thank for your feedback and upvote otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try Giving the complete path of the module folder. If you are running it on a remote machine you can make use of **os** **Module** to get the absolute path.

```
import sys
from os import path as expath
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(r'module/'))
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is happening is that `main.py` is importing everything from `mod.py`. At that moment python will execute line after line from `mod.py` but the first line of `mod.py` is importing everything from `main.py` again. So now python will execute line for line from `main.py` again. Since `mod.py` has already been previously imported python will not go back again to `mod.py` and continue line for line until it hits `print_it()` which, at that point, has not yet been defined because `mod.py` has not yet been fully executed due to the import statement in `mod.py`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744410/2027280) explains the same idea with some good examples.