# python derived class call a global variable which initialized in superclass

Tags: python, inheritance, global-variables

i tried initialized the derived class by default superclass's __init__function, then i tried to use the global variable which initialized in the init function.
but there was an error message said the variable "dr" in class One is not defined

base.py:

```
class Base(object):
    dr = None
    def __init__(self, driver):
        global dr
        dr = driver
```

one.py

```
class One(Base):
    def fun(self):
        print(dr)

if __name__=="__main__":
    driver = 1
    test = One(driver)
    test.fun()
```

Comment: because in my real case, use the variable "dr"  much times, i don't think it's good to pass it with every function, or initialize it in every class

Comment: Which variable? As shown, I'd expect a `NameError` when looking for `Base`. Why not make `dr` an instance attribute?

Comment: I omitted the import statement, hope you don't mind..

Comment: It's not a major problem, but a [mcve] would be ideal.

Comment: i mean the variable "dr" in class One. The error message said "dr" variable is not defined

Comment: You know you can [edit] the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `dr` as a class variable, a static field available to all classes, and you should see this field from all objects with `Base.dr`. 
`global` should not be used in methods, but rather in functions.

This class variable is not inherited and `One.dr` is not defined.

To be able to access `dr` in objects of the subclass you need to make it an  instance variable. Modify your base class as

```
class Base(object):
    #dr = None # this will differ from self.dr even if you let it here
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.dr = driver
```

You can use it in the subclass as

```
class One(Base):

    def __init__(self,driver): 
        super(Base, self).__init__(driver) #call constructor of superclass
    def fun(self):
        print(self.dr)
```

Comment: haha, i know this can solve my problem, but i just don't want to add "self." everywhere, i am so lazy. but thanks still

Comment: Reading the comment on the other post you should define a static method to import them from the `Base` class  as simple as `dr=Base.dr`

Answer (score 1):

That's because `global` stands for the global scope of a module, so the global scope of `base.py` isn't the same global scope in `one.py`, thus `global` won't work. Here's a solution for cross-module variable sharing https://stackoverflow.com/a/142566/4472389. But just avoid this type of code.

Comment: But it's still need using module name to call this variable. In my case, i want to this variable initialize once, and use in all subclass...just like it is used in superclass, don't need self. or module_name. to access

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i edit my code like this:

base.py:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.dr = driver
        global dr
        dr = driver
```

one.py

```
class One(Base):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        global dr
        dr = self.dr

    def fun(self):
        print(dr)

if __name__=="__main__":
    driver = 1
    test = One(driver)
    test.fun()
```

Maybe it's not very elegant, and i don't know if it is a good solution, but i can use "dr" variable in derived classes as many times as i want, and don't need the "self" to call it.