# Cannot access global variable inside a parent class (python)

Tags: python-3.x

So I have this code (parent class in ***file_1.py***):

```
class do_something():    
    def __init__(self, day, month, year):
        self.day = day
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        
    def set_message(self, s): 
        global var_1_global
        self.var_1 = var_1_global
```

which is inherited by child class (in ***file_2.py***) like that:

```
from file_1 import do_something
var_1_global = ""

class child_do_something(...,do_something,..):
    ...
```

The code is much larger, but I cannot put it in stackoverflow. I put only the key code. So the error I get is this:

```
NameError: name 'var_1_global ' is not defined
```

and shows the line in parent class (file_1.py) and more specifically:

```
self.var_1 = var_1_global
```

I have searched and found this: [python derived class call a global variable which initialized in superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142145/python-derived-class-call-a-global-variable-which-initialized-in-superclass) which does not help. Any idea what I am missing here and how to fix it?

Comment: Try replacing `global var_1_global` by `from file_2 import var_1_global` in method `set_message`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would be correct if `var_1_global` was defined in
`file_1.py`.  Here your `global var_1_global` statement has no effect
since `var_1_global` is not in your global scope.  Since it belongs to
another file you have to import it from `file_2`.

However since `file_2` already imports `do_something` from `file_1` at
the top level.  Putting this:

```py
from file_2 import var_1_global
```

at the top level of `file_1` would result in a cyclic import.
Therefore you have to perform this import in method `set_message` to
avoid that cycle issue.  A solution is therefore to change:

```py
    def set_message(self, s): 
        global var_1_global
        self.var_1 = var_1_global
```

by:

```py
    def set_message(self, s): 
        from file_2 import var_1_global
        self.var_1 = var_1_global
```