# Python import global variables

Tags: python, import, global-variables

I have file2.py:

```
def add(b):
    global a
    return (a+b)
```

In file1.py:

```
a = 1
from file2 import *
print(add(3))
```

it gave me an error: `NameError: global name 'a' is not defined`

How can I get the number 4?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The variable a is created in the global of file1.py You can pass the variable a directly to the add(a,b) and it should be easier. Or is it an exercise?

Comment: Why dont define you function add(a, b): ??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142545/python-how-to-make-a-cross-module-variable

Comment: I have a complex optimization objective function that takes only one input variable(like the function "add" in the post). now I want to add more variables to the function without changing the original objective function.

Comment: The original objective function as you said is already modified at the moment you are adding the "global a" you wrote above, isn't it?

Comment: Hello Macro, sorry for the confusion. yes, i changed the objective function. I mean I don't want to change the optimization program as it only accepts objective function with a single input variable.

Comment: Thank you, Chris_Rands! these two posts are very helpful!

Comment: If you can make a small change I would use the first attached post of Chris and you will not have to screw up too much!! Hope this is enough to solve your query ;) Have a nice day.