# Python3 `builtins` is not always `__builtins__`

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was putting this idea [How to make a cross-module variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142545/how-to-make-a-cross-module-variable) in action for python3.
And was lazy enough to use the variable `__builtins__` instead of the module `builtins`. Which should make no difference because:

```
# file spam.py:
import builtins
print (builtins is __builtins__)
print (id(builtins))
print (id(__builtins__))
```

This is when it gets funny: `builtins` is not `__builtins__` when imported:

```
$ python3 spam.py 
True
140598001743336
140598001743336

$ python3 -c 'import spam'
False
139755426543080
139755426520904
```

Does anyone know what happens?

(A comment on the given page mentions "`__builtins__` is a CPython peculiarity, you really shouldn't use it", but I'm being curious...)

Comment: `__builtins__` is an implementation detail, so you shouldn't rely on it being anything in particular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really know why, but from [article](https://faster-cpython.readthedocs.io/mutable.html#builtin-functions)

> frame globals have a `__builtins__` variable (builtins dictionary, or
>   builtins module when `__name__` equals `__main__`)

so in your first case (`__name__ == __main__`) and you get `__builtins__` as `builtins` module, but in the second case (`__name__ != __main__`) `__builtins__` is a `dict` instance and from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html):

> The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value
>   of this module’s `__dict__` attribute.

## Test

With slightly modified `spam.py`

```
import builtins

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(type(__builtins__))
    print(__builtins__ is builtins)
    print(id(builtins))
    print(id(__builtins__))
else:
    print(type(__builtins__))
    print(__builtins__ is builtins.__dict__)
    print(id(builtins.__dict__))
    print(id(__builtins__))
```

we will get something like

```
$ python3 spam.py 
<class 'module'>
True
2345652270648
2345652270648

$ python3 -c 'import spam'
<class 'dict'>
True
2770543697736
2770543697736
```

## Conclusion

As you & @chepner have already noticed `__builtins__` is an implementation detail that can be changed, so we shouldn't rely on it, especially on it being a `builtins` module/`builtins.__dict__` object.

Answer (score 1):

For CPython implementation,

in the `__main__` module: `__builtins__ is builtins`.
in other module: `__builtins__ is builtins.__dict__`

Refs:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#builtins-and-restricted-execution
http://mathamy.com/whats-the-deal-with-builtins-vs-builtin.html